# Vuetify Datatable: customize dropdown menu for sorting below mobilebreakpoint

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify (2.6.1) data tables and they work great.
I wonder if it is possible to customize the UI of a particular case:
-> when the v-data-table is in responsive into the mobile breakpoint.

The UI looks like this:

[data table list on mobile - sort field highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVKVs.png)

Is it possible, just in this case, to customize the select highlighted in red here ?
I tried to update the the global CSS but things are not clean because when an item is selected from the list there is a v-chip added:

[data table list on mobile with sort selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjQwf.png)

I would like the select to look like and behave just like in this case here highlighted in red:

[vuetify documentation - select solo style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut312.png)

I searched on the documentation and API, stack overflow, vuetify github's and tried different ways but I haven't found a way on how to properly style the sort select input.

Is anyone have any idea ? Maybe I'm missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic slots `item.<name>` and customise `v-select` or `v-autocomplete` inside: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item

Comment: How could I do that ? As far as I know the `v-select`  here to choose sorting is dynamically generated by the `v-data-table` with the `options` computed from the header columns. I haven't found this use case in the link provided from the documentation.   It would be perfect to add the `solo` directive on all `v-select` on parent config or on this dynamically generated `v-select` from the `v-data-table`

Comment: Check slots: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item

Comment: I'm using slots as you can see in the screenshot for the top part.  I would have preferred to not remove and rewrite all the logic of sorting just to change the default style applied in the v-select generated by the mobile version of v-data-table. Maybe I don't have a choice here

Comment: What component do you use for 'Trier par'?

Comment: I'm only using a `v-data-table` for the whole screenshot and vuetify automatically generates a `v-select` for the "Trier par" component when the width goes below 600px. When I read the source code of vuetify in `VDataTableHeaderMobile.js` line 40 there is a `genSortSelect` method where this `Trier par` component comes from

Comment: You can use the dynamic slots `item.<name>` and use `v-autocomplete` inside: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item

Comment: I'm using this method to customize different "cell" types (external link in this case).  But with `item.<name>` I can't seem to have access to the generated `v-select` generated here by vuetify for sorting. I might be able to remove completely the default sorting and replace it with a manual version using my own `v-select`or `v-autocomplete`but I can't seem to be able to customize the default behavior to add a `solo`directive with the method you propose.

Comment: Correct, that's what my suggestion is about. Unfortunately, there is no 'solo' directive which you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time helping me out. Do you know if it's possible to override the default value for the global use of `v-select` accross a project to force the `solo` directive on all `v-select` ?

Comment: No. It seems it might be implemented only in v3: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9677#issuecomment-757010990

Comment: I have changes the answer to a summary from our discussion

Comment: Thank you for you help Andrei, you've been really helpful :)